# Add to homescreen popup on page - open another URL

Tags: javascript, web-applications, homescreen

Is there a way to make the webapp open another link than added.
For example.
The popup came on www.thisurl.com. But.. when added to homescreen I want it to open www.thisurl.com/subpage

We want them to add to homescreen on a customer portal, but when clicked on the app-icon we want them to go to a loginpage.

Is there a way to maybe put in some javascript?
I've been searching all over the internet by now and just can't find the answer (i'm not a code ninja :-) )
Ps. It's on iphone.

Here's my html code:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../laaneovervaagning150x150.png">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Overvågning">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../addtohomescreen/style/add2home.css" />


<!-- add to homescreen funktionalitet -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var addToHomeConfig = {
            lifespan: 20000,
            expire: 43200,
            touchIcon: true
        };
    </script>
```

Javascript code attached you can find here.

```
    /*!
 * Add to Homescreen v2.0.7 ~ Copyright (c) 2013 Matteo Spinelli, http://cubiq.org
 * Released under MIT license, http://cubiq.org/license
 */
var addToHome = (function (w) {
    var nav = w.navigator,
        isIDevice = 'platform' in nav && (/iphone|ipod|ipad/gi).test(nav.platform),
        isIPad,
        isRetina,
        isSafari,
        isStandalone,
        OSVersion,
        startX = 0,
        startY = 0,
        lastVisit = 0,
        isExpired,
        isSessionActive,
        isReturningVisitor,
        balloon,
        overrideChecks,

        positionInterval,
        closeTimeout,

        options = {
            autostart: true,            // Automatically open the balloon
            returningVisitor: false,    // Show the balloon to returning visitors only (setting this to true is HIGHLY RECCOMENDED)
            animationIn: 'drop',        // drop || bubble || fade
            animationOut: 'fade',       // drop || bubble || fade
            startDelay: 2000,           // 2 seconds from page load before the balloon appears
            lifespan: 15000,            // 15 seconds before it is automatically destroyed
            bottomOffset: 14,           // Distance of the balloon from bottom
            expire: 0,                  // Minutes to wait before showing the popup again (0 = always displayed)
            message: '',                // Customize your message or force a language ('' = automatic)
            touchIcon: false,           // Display the touch icon
            arrow: true,                // Display the balloon arrow
            hookOnLoad: true,           // Should we hook to onload event? (really advanced usage)
            closeButton: true,          // Let the user close the balloon
            iterations: 100             // Internal/debug use
        },

        intl = {
            ar:    '<span dir="rtl">Ù‚Ù… Ø¨ØªØ«Ø¨ÙŠØª Ù‡Ø°Ø§ Ø§Ù„ØªØ·Ø¨ÙŠÙ‚ Ø¹Ù„Ù‰ <span dir="ltr">%device:</span>Ø§Ù†Ù‚Ø±<span dir="ltr">%icon</span> ØŒ<strong>Ø«Ù… Ø§Ø¶ÙÙ‡ Ø§Ù„Ù‰ Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø§Ø´Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø¦ÙŠØ³ÙŠØ©.</strong></span>',
            ca_es: 'Per instalÂ·lar aquesta aplicaciÃ³ al vostre %device premeu %icon i llavors <strong>Afegir a pantalla d\'inici</strong>.',
            cs_cz: 'Pro instalaci aplikace na VÃ¡Å¡ %device, stisknÄ›te %icon a v nabÃ­dce <strong>PÅ™idat na plochu</strong>.',
            da_dk: 'Tryk på %icon og derefter <strong>Føj til hjemmeskærm</strong> for nem adgang til låneovervågning.',
            de_de: 'Installieren Sie diese App auf Ihrem %device: %icon antippen und dann <strong>Zum Home-Bildschirm</strong>.',
            el_gr: 'Î•Î³ÎºÎ±Ï„Î±ÏƒÏ„Î®ÏƒÎµÏ„Îµ Î±Ï…Ï„Î®Î½ Ï„Î·Î½ Î•Ï†Î±ÏÎ¼Î¿Î³Î® ÏƒÏ„Î®Î½ ÏƒÏ…ÏƒÎºÎµÏ…Î® ÏƒÎ±Ï‚ %device: %icon Î¼ÎµÏ„Î¬ Ï€Î±Ï„Î¬Ï„Îµ <strong>Î ÏÎ¿ÏƒÎ¸Î®ÎºÎ· ÏƒÎµ Î‘Ï†ÎµÏ„Î·ÏÎ¯Î±</strong>.',
            /*en_us: 'Install this web app on your %device: tap %icon and then <strong>Add to Home Screen</strong>.',*/
            en_us: 'Tryk på %icon og derefter <strong>Føj til hjemmeskærm</strong> for nem adgang til låneovervågning.',
            es_es: 'Para instalar esta app en su %device, pulse %icon y seleccione <strong>AÃ±adir a pantalla de inicio</strong>.',
            fi_fi: 'Asenna tÃ¤mÃ¤ web-sovellus laitteeseesi %device: paina %icon ja sen jÃ¤lkeen valitse <strong>LisÃ¤Ã¤ Koti-valikkoon</strong>.',
            fr_fr: 'Ajoutez cette application sur votre %device en cliquant sur %icon, puis <strong>Ajouter Ã  l\'Ã©cran d\'accueil</strong>.',
            he_il: '<span dir="rtl">×”×ª×§×Ÿ ××¤×œ×™×§×¦×™×” ×–×• ×¢×œ ×”-%device ×©×œ×š: ×”×§×© %icon ×•××– <strong>×”×•×¡×£ ×œ×ž×¡×š ×”×‘×™×ª</strong>.</span>',
            hr_hr: 'Instaliraj ovu aplikaciju na svoj %device: klikni na %icon i odaberi <strong>Dodaj u poÄetni zaslon</strong>.',
            hu_hu: 'TelepÃ­tse ezt a web-alkalmazÃ¡st az Ã–n %device-jÃ¡ra: nyomjon a %icon-ra majd a <strong>FÅ‘kÃ©pernyÅ‘hÃ¶z adÃ¡s</strong> gombra.',
            it_it: 'Installa questa applicazione sul tuo %device: premi su %icon e poi <strong>Aggiungi a Home</strong>.',
            ja_jp: 'ã“ã®ã‚¦ã‚§ãƒ–ã‚¢ãƒ—ãƒªã‚’ã‚ãªãŸã®%deviceã«ã‚¤ãƒ³ã‚¹ãƒˆãƒ¼ãƒ«ã™ã‚‹ã«ã¯%iconã‚’ã‚¿ãƒƒãƒ—ã—ã¦<strong>ãƒ›ãƒ¼ãƒ ç”»é¢ã«è¿½åŠ </strong>ã‚’é¸ã‚“ã§ãã ã•ã„ã€‚',
            ko_kr: '%deviceì— ì›¹ì•±ì„ ì„¤ì¹˜í•˜ë ¤ë©´ %iconì„ í„°ì¹˜ í›„ "í™ˆí™”ë©´ì— ì¶”ê°€"ë¥¼ ì„ íƒí•˜ì„¸ìš”',
            nb_no: 'Installer denne appen pÃ¥ din %device: trykk pÃ¥ %icon og deretter <strong>Legg til pÃ¥ Hjem-skjerm</strong>',
            nl_nl: 'Installeer deze webapp op uw %device: tik %icon en dan <strong>Voeg toe aan beginscherm</strong>.',
            pl_pl: 'Aby zainstalowaÄ‡ tÄ™ aplikacje na %device: naciÅ›nij %icon a nastÄ™pnie <strong>Dodaj jako ikonÄ™</strong>.',
            pt_br: 'Instale este aplicativo em seu %device: aperte %icon e selecione <strong>Adicionar Ã  Tela Inicio</strong>.',
            pt_pt: 'Para instalar esta aplicaÃ§Ã£o no seu %device, prima o %icon e depois o <strong>Adicionar ao ecrÃ£ principal</strong>.',
            ru_ru: 'Ð£ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ ÑÑ‚Ð¾ Ð²ÐµÐ±-Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð»Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð½Ð° Ð²Ð°Ñˆ %device: Ð½Ð°Ð¶Ð¼Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ %icon, Ð·Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ¼ <strong>Ð”Ð¾Ð±Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð² Â«Ð”Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ð¹Â»</strong>.',
            sv_se: 'LÃ¤gg till denna webbapplikation pÃ¥ din %device: tryck pÃ¥ %icon och dÃ¤refter <strong>LÃ¤gg till pÃ¥ hemskÃ¤rmen</strong>.',
            th_th: 'à¸•à¸´à¸”à¸•à¸±à¹‰à¸‡à¹€à¸§à¹‡à¸šà¹à¸­à¸žà¸¯ à¸™à¸µà¹‰à¸šà¸™ %device à¸‚à¸­à¸‡à¸„à¸¸à¸“: à¹à¸•à¸° %icon à¹à¸¥à¸° <strong>à¹€à¸žà¸´à¹ˆà¸¡à¸—à¸µà¹ˆà¸«à¸™à¹‰à¸²à¸ˆà¸­à¹‚à¸®à¸¡</strong>',
            tr_tr: 'Bu uygulamayÄ± %device\'a eklemek iÃ§in %icon simgesine sonrasÄ±nda <strong>Ana Ekrana Ekle</strong> dÃ¼ÄŸmesine basÄ±n.',
            uk_ua: 'Ð’ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ñ–Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ†ÐµÐ¹ Ð²ÐµÐ± ÑÐ°Ð¹Ñ‚ Ð½Ð° Ð’Ð°Ñˆ %device: Ð½Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸ÑÐ½Ñ–Ñ‚ÑŒ %icon, Ð° Ð¿Ð¾Ñ‚Ñ–Ð¼ <strong>ÐÐ° Ð¿Ð¾Ñ‡Ð°Ñ‚ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð¸Ð¹ ÐµÐºÑ€Ð°Ð½</strong>.',
            zh_cn: 'æ‚¨å¯ä»¥å°†æ­¤åº”ç”¨ç¨‹å¼å®‰è£…åˆ°æ‚¨çš„ %device ä¸Šã€‚è¯·æŒ‰ %icon ç„¶åŽç‚¹é€‰<strong>æ·»åŠ è‡³ä¸»å±å¹•</strong>ã€‚',
            zh_tw: 'æ‚¨å¯ä»¥å°‡æ­¤æ‡‰ç”¨ç¨‹å¼å®‰è£åˆ°æ‚¨çš„ %device ä¸Šã€‚è«‹æŒ‰ %icon ç„¶å¾Œé»žé¸<strong>åŠ å…¥ä¸»ç•«é¢èž¢å¹•</strong>ã€‚'
        };

    function init () {
        // Preliminary check, all further checks are performed on iDevices only
        if ( !isIDevice ) return;

        var now = Date.now(),
            i;

        // Merge local with global options
        if ( w.addToHomeConfig ) {
            for ( i in w.addToHomeConfig ) {
                options[i] = w.addToHomeConfig[i];
            }
        }
        if ( !options.autostart ) options.hookOnLoad = false;

        isIPad = (/ipad/gi).test(nav.platform);
        isRetina = w.devicePixelRatio && w.devicePixelRatio > 1;
        isSafari = (/Safari/i).test(nav.appVersion) && !(/CriOS/i).test(nav.appVersion);
        isStandalone = nav.standalone;
        OSVersion = nav.appVersion.match(/OS (\d+_\d+)/i);
        OSVersion = OSVersion && OSVersion[1] ? +OSVersion[1].replace('_', '.') : 0;

        lastVisit = +w.localStorage.getItem('addToHome');

        isSessionActive = w.sessionStorage.getItem('addToHomeSession');
        isReturningVisitor = options.returningVisitor ? lastVisit && lastVisit + 28*24*60*60*1000 > now : true;

        if ( !lastVisit ) lastVisit = now;

        // If it is expired we need to reissue a new balloon
        isExpired = isReturningVisitor && lastVisit <= now;

        if ( options.hookOnLoad ) w.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
        else if ( !options.hookOnLoad && options.autostart ) loaded();
    }

    function loaded () {



        w.removeEventListener('load', loaded, false);

        if ( !isReturningVisitor ) w.localStorage.setItem('addToHome', Date.now());
        else if ( options.expire && isExpired ) w.localStorage.setItem('addToHome', Date.now() + options.expire * 60000);

        if ( !overrideChecks && ( !isSafari || !isExpired || isSessionActive || isStandalone || !isReturningVisitor ) ) return;

        var touchIcon = '',
            platform = nav.platform.split(' ')[0],
            language = nav.language.replace('-', '_');

        balloon = document.createElement('div');
        balloon.id = 'addToHomeScreen';
        balloon.style.cssText += 'left:-9999px;-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform,opacity;-webkit-transition-duration:0;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);position:' + (OSVersion < 5 ? 'absolute' : 'fixed');

        // Localize message
        if ( options.message in intl ) {        // You may force a language despite the user's locale
            language = options.message;
            options.message = '';
        }
        if ( options.message === '' ) {         // We look for a suitable language (defaulted to en_us)
            options.message = language in intl ? intl[language] : intl['en_us'];
        }

        if ( options.touchIcon ) {
            touchIcon = isRetina ?
                document.querySelector('head link[rel^=apple-touch-icon][sizes="114x114"],head link[rel^=apple-touch-icon][sizes="144x144"],head link[rel^=apple-touch-icon]') :
                document.querySelector('head link[rel^=apple-touch-icon][sizes="57x57"],head link[rel^=apple-touch-icon]');

            if ( touchIcon ) {
                touchIcon = '<span style="background-image:url(' + touchIcon.href + ')" class="addToHomeTouchIcon"></span>';
            }
        }

        balloon.className = (isIPad ? 'addToHomeIpad' : 'addToHomeIphone') + (touchIcon ? ' addToHomeWide' : '');
        balloon.innerHTML = touchIcon +
            options.message.replace('%device', platform).replace('%icon', OSVersion >= 4.2 ? '<span class="addToHomeShare"></span>' : '<span class="addToHomePlus">+</span>') +
            (options.arrow ? '<span class="addToHomeArrow"></span>' : '') +
            (options.closeButton ? '<span class="addToHomeClose">\u00D7</span>' : '');

        document.body.appendChild(balloon);

        // Add the close action
        if ( options.closeButton ) balloon.addEventListener('click', clicked, false);

        if ( !isIPad && OSVersion >= 6 ) window.addEventListener('orientationchange', orientationCheck, false);

        setTimeout(show, options.startDelay);
    }

    function show () {
        var duration,
            iPadXShift = 208;

        // Set the initial position
        if ( isIPad ) {
            if ( OSVersion < 5 ) {
                startY = w.scrollY;
                startX = w.scrollX;
            } else if ( OSVersion < 6 ) {
                iPadXShift = 160;
            }

            balloon.style.top = startY + options.bottomOffset + 'px';
            balloon.style.left = startX + iPadXShift - Math.round(balloon.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';

            switch ( options.animationIn ) {
                case 'drop':
                    duration = '0.6s';
                    balloon.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,' + -(w.scrollY + options.bottomOffset + balloon.offsetHeight) + 'px,0)';
                    break;
                case 'bubble':
                    duration = '0.6s';
                    balloon.style.opacity = '0';
                    balloon.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,' + (startY + 50) + 'px,0)';
                    break;
                default:
                    duration = '1s';
                    balloon.style.opacity = '0';
            }
        } else {
            startY = w.innerHeight + w.scrollY;

            if ( OSVersion < 5 ) {
                startX = Math.round((w.innerWidth - balloon.offsetWidth) / 2) + w.scrollX;
                balloon.style.left = startX + 'px';
                balloon.style.top = startY - balloon.offsetHeight - options.bottomOffset + 'px';
            } else {
                balloon.style.left = '50%';
                balloon.style.marginLeft = -Math.round(balloon.offsetWidth / 2) - ( w.orientation%180 && OSVersion >= 6 ? 40 : 0 ) + 'px';
                balloon.style.bottom = options.bottomOffset + 'px';
            }

            switch (options.animationIn) {
                case 'drop':
                    duration = '1s';
                    balloon.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,' + -(startY + options.bottomOffset) + 'px,0)';
                    break;
                case 'bubble':
                    duration = '0.6s';
                    balloon.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,' + (balloon.offsetHeight + options.bottomOffset + 50) + 'px,0)';
                    break;
                default:
                    duration = '1s';
                    balloon.style.opacity = '0';
            }
        }

        balloon.offsetHeight;   // repaint trick
        balloon.style.webkitTransitionDuration = duration;
        balloon.style.opacity = '1';
        balloon.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,0,0)';
        balloon.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', transitionEnd, false);

        closeTimeout = setTimeout(close, options.lifespan);
    }

    function manualShow (override) {
        if ( !isIDevice || balloon ) return;

        overrideChecks = override;
        loaded();
    }

    function close () {
        clearInterval( positionInterval );
        clearTimeout( closeTimeout );
        closeTimeout = null;

        // check if the popup is displayed and prevent errors
        if ( !balloon ) return;

        var posY = 0,
            posX = 0,
            opacity = '1',
            duration = '0';

        if ( options.closeButton ) balloon.removeEventListener('click', clicked, false);
        if ( !isIPad && OSVersion >= 6 ) window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', orientationCheck, false);

        if ( OSVersion < 5 ) {
            posY = isIPad ? w.scrollY - startY : w.scrollY + w.innerHeight - startY;
            posX = isIPad ? w.scrollX - startX : w.scrollX + Math.round((w.innerWidth - balloon.offsetWidth)/2) - startX;
        }

        balloon.style.webkitTransitionProperty = '-webkit-transform,opacity';

        switch ( options.animationOut ) {
            case 'drop':
                if ( isIPad ) {
                    duration = '0.4s';
                    opacity = '0';
                    posY += 50;
                } else {
                    duration = '0.6s';
                    posY += balloon.offsetHeight + options.bottomOffset + 50;
                }
                break;
            case 'bubble':
                if ( isIPad ) {
                    duration = '0.8s';
                    posY -= balloon.offsetHeight + options.bottomOffset + 50;
                } else {
                    duration = '0.4s';
                    opacity = '0';
                    posY -= 50;
                }
                break;
            default:
                duration = '0.8s';
                opacity = '0';
        }

        balloon.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', transitionEnd, false);
        balloon.style.opacity = opacity;
        balloon.style.webkitTransitionDuration = duration;
        balloon.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px,0)';
    }


    function clicked () {
        w.sessionStorage.setItem('addToHomeSession', '1');
        isSessionActive = true;
        close();
    }

    function transitionEnd () {
        balloon.removeEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', transitionEnd, false);

        balloon.style.webkitTransitionProperty = '-webkit-transform';
        balloon.style.webkitTransitionDuration = '0.2s';

        // We reached the end!
        if ( !closeTimeout ) {
            balloon.parentNode.removeChild(balloon);
            balloon = null;
            return;
        }

        // On iOS 4 we start checking the element position
        if ( OSVersion < 5 && closeTimeout ) positionInterval = setInterval(setPosition, options.iterations);
    }

    function setPosition () {
        var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(w.getComputedStyle(balloon, null).webkitTransform),
            posY = isIPad ? w.scrollY - startY : w.scrollY + w.innerHeight - startY,
            posX = isIPad ? w.scrollX - startX : w.scrollX + Math.round((w.innerWidth - balloon.offsetWidth) / 2) - startX;

        // Screen didn't move
        if ( posY == matrix.m42 && posX == matrix.m41 ) return;

        balloon.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px,0)';
    }

    // Clear local and session storages (this is useful primarily in development)
    function reset () {
        w.localStorage.removeItem('addToHome');
        w.sessionStorage.removeItem('addToHomeSession');
    }

    function orientationCheck () {
        balloon.style.marginLeft = -Math.round(balloon.offsetWidth / 2) - ( w.orientation%180 && OSVersion >= 6 ? 40 : 0 ) + 'px';
    }

    // Bootstrap!
    init();

    return {
        show: manualShow,
        close: close,
        reset: reset
    };
})(window);
```

Answer (score 2):

This plugin seems to just create a popup that prompts the user to use the native menu options to add the current page to the home screen. It doesn't actually add the page to the user's home screen itself, so you can't customise the url.

There is an alternative on Android (and hopefully other platforms soon), and that is to make your site a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) (PWA). If Android detects that your site is a PWA, it can automatically show a prompt that *does* actually add the page to the user's home screen.

As part of building a PWA, you'll create a [manifest.json](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) file. This file has a setting `start_url` that you can use to specify which page will be loaded from the home screen icon.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I guess I will wait then or find another solution :/ - but I can check out the android part and see if I can get it to work there.

thank you! :-)